# Cannot import Apollo resolvers

Tags: typescript, apollo-client, apollo-server

I have a Apollo query:

```
// ./src/resolvers.js

const Movie = {
  id: (parent) => parent.id,
  name: (parent) => parent.name,
  tmdb_id: (parent) => parent.tmdb_id,
};

const Query = {
  movies: () => {
    return prisma.movie.findMany({});
  },
};
```

And in my dashboard component I'm trying to return the data from Apollo:

```
// ./src/dashboard.tsx

const DashboardComponent = () => {
  const {loading, error, data} = useQuery(resolvers.Query.movies);

  ...
}
```

But TSlint is showing an error:

> TS2345: Argument of type '() => PrismaPromise<Movie[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DocumentNode | TypedDocumentNode<any, OperationVariables>'.
> Type '() => PrismaPromise<Movie[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'TypedDocumentNode<any, OperationVariables>': kind, definitions

I'm using:

```
"prisma": "2.30.0",
"typescript": "^4.3.5",
"apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
"apollo-server": "^3.2.0",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useQuery()` accepts a [query](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#query) parameter which type is `DocumentNode`.  You can't pass a resolver to it.

`DocumentNode`:

> A GraphQL query document parsed into an AST by `gql`.

The GraphQL resolver is used to resolve the fields defined in the GraphQL schema. In actual use, it is generally placed on the server-side, set up a GraphQL server, serving over HTTP with Database, REST API as its data source.

GraphQL resolver is placed on the data production side, and the consumer side defines the fields that need to be queried by constructing `DocumentNode` AST.

GraphQL only defines the exchange method between the data production end and the consumer end and has nothing to do with the specific upper-layer communication protocol HTTP, RPC, etc.

See [Is GraphQL frontend or backend?](https://graphql.org/faq/#is-graphql-frontend-or-backend) and [Does GraphQL use HTTP?](https://graphql.org/faq/#does-graphql-use-http)

You should create your query on the client-side like this:

```js
import { gql, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';

const QUERY_MOVIES = gql`
  query QueryMovies {
     movies {
       id
       name
     }
  }
`

// In React component
useQuery(QUERY_MOVIES);
```

Comment: Great! Do you perchance know if it's possible to use Prisma in the Apollo client like this? ps. i think you forget the `export default QUERY_MOVIES` in your answer

Comment: Am I understanding it correctly that resolvers should not be used for direct use within a client? Than what are resolvers used for?

Comment: By the way, I don't think you need the argument for the `query QueryMovies()` Gave me an error: `GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Expected "$", found ")".` Removing the `()` > ` `query QueryMovies` fixed it for me.